# The disk image is invalid in vmware, however perfect when used in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

We have a vmware workstation with several windows virtuals and a single linux.

There was a power cut and after system has booted up i noticed that windows are working good, however linux virtual machine can not load.

Linux machine has 2 virtual HDD assigned and vmware shows 'Hard disk not valid' for both of them.
I have removed both of them from the list of hardware and then tried to readd but kept getting 'The selected file is not a valid virtual disk file.'.

I then made a copy of the virtual machine. Inside oracle Virtualbox i have created a new virtual for linux and assigned both of the HDD images to it. To my suprise it ran, to some point.
There is Arch linux installed. when it boots and if i select to boot up normaly it will stop and throw an error about it not being able to locate one of the volumes with specified UUID.
Rebooting and selecting 'fallback' option boots up normally with no errors. I have checked and the drive with same UUID was present and mounted where it should be.

What can i do to make work on vmware again? Why does virtualbox runs the machine?
It does seem like the images are ok, so why does vmware not like them?

Comment: what sort of disk image?

Comment: not sure if there are other types and if you are asking what i think you are asking. It's a vmware virtual disk .vmdk